# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost.sklearn'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I'm trying to import xgboost into jupyter-notebook but get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-a585b270d0df> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 import xgboost

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/__init__.py in <module>
     14 from . import tracker  # noqa
     15 from .tracker import RabitTracker  # noqa
---> 16 from . import dask
     17 try:
     18     from .sklearn import XGBModel, XGBClassifier, XGBRegressor, XGBRanker

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/dask.py in <module>
     31 from .training import train as worker_train
     32 from .tracker import RabitTracker
---> 33 from .sklearn import XGBModel, XGBClassifierBase, xgboost_model_doc
     34 
     35 # Current status is considered as initial support, many features are

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost.sklearn'
```

I've downloaded sklearn as well as sci-kit learn and they work fine...
Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Hi Sam_K, please familiarise yourself with [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you write your next question! Enjoy your stay at SO :)

Comment: @Sam_K did you, after that, download xgboost using pip ?

Comment: 1- close `jupyter notebook`, 2- install your package (`pip(3)`) 3- make sure you are installing and running from the same place(not install on machine's python and run on virtual environment)

Answer (score 2):

You might need to install your packages properly.
For best practice, you'll need to use a conda environment. Check out how it works here: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Once you have created your environment, activate it and then install all the packages you need. Presumably, you'll have to run the command:

- conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
- pip install -U scikit-learn

To install your machine learning packages.

Answer (score 1):

XGBoost is in the `xgboost` module. It should be imported as:

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
```

Answer (score 0):

Install these 2 packages:

```
pip install xgboost
pip install scikit-learn
```

or

```
python -m pip install xgboost
python -m pip install scikit-learn
```

for `ipynb` file:

```
!pip install xgboost
!pip install scikit-learn
```