# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dask_xgboost'

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, dask, dask-ml

I am trying to run dask_ml functions but the system does not accept my installation and gives and error when I import it. OS: Linux ubuntu 20.

**[Installation to conda environment](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/dask-ml)**

```
conda install -c conda-forge dask-ml
```

**Import**

```
#dask
from dask_ml.xgboost import XGBClassifier
```

**ERROR**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-148-885097890294> in <module>
      1 #dask
----> 2 from dask_ml.xgboost import XGBClassifier

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask_ml/xgboost.py in <module>
      5 ``dask.distributed`` cluster.
      6 """
----> 7 from dask_xgboost import *  # noqa

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dask_xgboost'
```

**Possible Solutions**

- I have correctly installed mine - [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost.sklearn'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61800137/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-xgboost-sklearn)
- https://github.com/dask/dask-kubernetes/issues/134
- 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only installed some parts of dask you may also need to install xgboost separately to anaconda

```
conda install -c conda-forge dask-xgboost
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it seems you need to install other parts like `dask-xgboost` later. Even if you have already installed `dask["complete"]` and `dask-ml`.

Besides `conda` you can do it by ```pip`` also.

`pip install dask-xgboost`